# Dialogflow Fulfilment webhook call failed

Tags: javascript, firebase, dialogflow-es, javascript-objects, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

[image]I am new to dialogflow fulfillment and I am trying to retrieve news from news API based on user questions. I followed documentation provided by news API, but I am not able to catch any responses from the search results, when I run the function in console it is not errors. I changed the code and it looks like now it is reaching to the newsapi endpoint but it is not fetching any results. I am utilizing https://newsapi.org/docs/client-libraries/node-js to make a request to search everything about the topic. when I diagnoise the function it says " Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE. "

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const http = require('http');


const host = 'newsapi.org';
const NewsAPI = require('newsapi');
const newsapi = new NewsAPI('63756dc5caca424fb3d0343406295021');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>
{
  // Get the city 
  let search = req.body.queryResult.parameters['search'];// search is a required param
  

  // Call the weather API
  callNewsApi(search).then((response) => {
    res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': response }); // Return the results of the news API to Dialogflow
  }).catch((xx) => {
    console.error(xx);
    res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': `I don't know the news but I hope it's good!` });
  });
});

function callNewsApi(search) 
{
  console.log(search);
  newsapi.v2.everything
  (
    { 
        q: 'search',
        langauge: 'en',
        sortBy: 'relevancy',
        source: 'cbc-news',
        domains: 'cbc.ca',
        from: '2019-12-31',
        to: '2020-12-12',
        page: 2
    }
  ).then (response => {console.log(response);
                       {                               

                      
     let articles = response['data']['articles'][0];
                      

        // Create response
        
let responce = `Current news in the $search with following title is  ${articles['titile']} which says that 
        ${articles['description']}`;

        // Resolve the promise with the output text
        console.log(output);
       
                       }
   });  
  

}
```

Also here is RAW API response

```
{
  "responseId": "a871b8d2-16f2-4873-a5d1-b907a07adb9a-b4ef8d5f",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "what is the latest news about toronto",
    "parameters": {
      "search": [
        "toronto"
      ]
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/misty-ktsarh/agent/intents/b52c5774-e5b7-494a-8f4c-f783ebae558b",
      "displayName": "misty.news"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 543
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 14,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE."
  },
  "outputAudio": "UklGRlQqAABXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAEAwF0AAIC7AAACABAAZGF0YTAqAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA... (The content is truncated. Click `COPY` for the original JSON.)",
  "outputAudioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "OUTPUT_AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16",
    "synthesizeSpeechConfig": {
      "speakingRate": 1,
      "voice": {}
    }
  }
}
```

And Here is fulfillment request:

```
{
  "responseId": "a871b8d2-16f2-4873-a5d1-b907a07adb9a-b4ef8d5f",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "what is the latest news about toronto",
    "parameters": {
      "search": [
        "toronto"
      ]
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/misty-ktsarh/agent/intents/b52c5774-e5b7-494a-8f4c-f783ebae558b",
      "displayName": "misty.news"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 543
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 14,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE."
  },
  "outputAudio": "UklGRlQqAABXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAEAwF0AAIC7AAACABAAZGF0YTAqAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA... (The content is truncated. Click `COPY` for the original JSON.)",
  "outputAudioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "OUTPUT_AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16",
    "synthesizeSpeechConfig": {
      "speakingRate": 1,
      "voice": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Also here is the screenshot from the firebase console. [image]

Can anyone guide me what is that I am missing in here?

Answer (score 2):

The key is the first three lines in the error message:

```
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'newsapi'
```

It is saying that the `newsapi` module couldn't be loaded and that the most likely cause of this is that you didn't list this as a dependency in your `package.json` file.

If you are using the Dialogflow Inline Editor, you need to select the `package.json` tab and add a line in the `dependencies` section.

[image: Inline Editor]

*Update*

It isn't clear exactly when/where you're getting the "UNAVAILABLE" error, but one likely cause if you're using Dialogflow's Inline Editor is that it is using the Firebase "Spark" pricing plan, which has limitations on network calls outside Google's network.

You can [upgrade to the Blaze plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), which does require a credit card on file, but does include the Spark plan's free tier, so you shouldn't incur any costs during light usage. This will allow for network calls.

*Update* based on `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

This indicates that either a property (or possibly an index of a property) is trying to reference against something that is undefined.

It isn't clear which line, exactly, this may be, but these lines all are suspicious:

```
    let response = JSON.parse(body);
    let source = response['data']['source'][0];
    let id = response['data']['id'][0];
    let name = response['data']['name'][0];
    let author = response['author'][0];
    let title = response['title'][0];
    let description = response['description'][0];
```

since they are all referencing a property. I would check to see exactly what comes back and gets stored in `response`. For example, could it be that there is no "data" or "author" field in what is sent back?

Looking at https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/everything, it looks like none of these *are* fields, but that there is an `articles` property sent back which contains an array of articles. You may wish to index off that and get the attributes you want.

*Update*

It looks like that, although you are loading the parameter into a variable with this line

```
// Get the city and date from the request
let search = req.body.queryResult.parameters['search'];// city is a required param
```

You don't actually use the `search` variable anywhere. Instead, you seem to be passing a literal string "search" to your function with this line

```
callNewsApi('search').then((output) => {
```

which does a search for the word "search", I guess.

You indicated that "it goes to the catch portion", which indicates that something went wrong in the call. You don't show any logging in the catch portion, and it may be useful to log the exception that is thrown, so you know *why* it is going to the catch portion. Something like

```
}).catch((xx) => {
  console.error(xx);
  res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': `I don't know the news but I hope it's good!` });
});
```

is normal, but since it looks like you're logging it in the `.on('error')` portion, showing that error might be useful.

Comment: it fixed the error but It is not fetching any results into responses

Comment: Please update the question to indicate any logs you may be recording, any errors you're getting, and what is happening when you're trying this.

Comment: I upgraded my plan to Blaze Plan.
But when I check the error messages over there it says 


    TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.res.on (/srv/index.js:54:51)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)

Comment: Please add that to your question. Trying to read errors in comments are exceptionally difficult.

Comment: I tried to index only articles into the responce and tried to use required attributes to built the responce. But when I check the dialogflow diagnostic info nothing is being passed as an input for the query and it goes to the catch portion and gives default response.


see the updated question with diagnostic info

Comment: Answer updated. But it would be helpful if you included a screen shot of the Intent you think should be triggered, along with the complete JSON request that is sent. Showing just the "outputContext" section doesn't help much.

Comment: @prisioner updated question with more information. Also added a screenshot for the intent.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the intent and the variable I was using to make the call had a difference in Casing, I guess calls are case sensitive just be aware of that